# JsonAlias Wildcard or regular expression

Tags: jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am trying to capture multiple things into a JsonAlias.  Below would suffice, but there are literally about 100 things I need to account for.

What I know I could do: @JsonAlias({"obj1", "obj2","obj3"})

Is it possible to do something like  @JsonAlias({"obj*"})

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: The Jackson deserializer doesn't treat strings from `@JsonAlias({"str1","str2"})` as regular expressions. You can achieve this by writing your own deserializer (and if you want to provide more customization, you can add a custom annotation e.g. `@CustomJsonAlias(expression = "regex")`). In your custom deserializer you can try to match strings with the desired regular expression.

Comment: I am now working on a custom deserializer and am am making good progress, however right now everything is hardcoded, similar to: blah.setBlah(node.get("blah").get(fieldName).get("blah1").get(fieldName1).get("blah2").  It is all working how I would like, the one thing that it is covering up is unknown data elements.  I would still like to fail on unknown data elements, but since I am specifically calling out the elements I want, It is no longer failing.  Any thoughts on how I could achieve still failing on unknown elements?

Comment: You can stop the process of deserialization by throwing a `JsonParseException` (for example when you encounter an unrecognized field or a required field is missing or anything similar that you think should prevent the deserialization). For instance: `throw new JsonParseException(parser, "Provide more info about the exception.");`